# Unicode: Character Count Shows More Characters in Notepad++ or MS Word

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, utf-8

I have to validate a unicode string (UTF-8) for invalid characters such as '^'. Also I have to show the position of the invalid character in the input string.
I have written the below code...

```
size_t getPositionByNumberOfChars(string input, size_t positionInBytes)
{
    size_t charPosition = 0;
    size_t bytesFromFront = 0;
    for (auto it = input.begin(), end = input.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (bytesFromFront == positionInBytes)  // Condition to break when found the exact position.
            break;
        bytesFromFront++;
        if ((*it & 0xc0) != 0x80)
            charPosition += 1;                  // We have found either an ASCII or UTF-8 Char.
    }
    return charPosition + 1;
}

void validateInputString(string inputData)
{
    vector<string> invalidUTF8Chars = {/*Some invalid chars*/};
    for (auto i : invalidUTF8Chars)
    {
        size_t pos = inputData.find(i, 0);
        if (pos != string::npos)
        {
            size_t charPosition = getPositionByNumberOfChars(inputData, pos);
            .
            .
            .
        }   
    }
}
```

This is giving proper output. But for some languages, the charPosition is incorrect...
Example: `ಭಾರ^^^^ತಭಾರತಕರ್ನಾಟಕ`

As per the above input, the invalid char(^) is present at position 3, but the variable `charPosition` gives me the count as 4.
Also the Notepad++ and MS Word gives total count as 19 but there are only 14 chars (ಭಾ|ರ|^|^|^|^|ತ|ಭಾ|ರ|ತ|ಕ|ರ್ನಾ|ಟ|ಕ). 
Is anything I am missing here?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)? Or that `"ಭಾ"` are really two characters that become one when followed by each other?

Comment: Yes, Just checked the Unicode page, it is the combination of 2 characters.

Comment: In general, determining the rendered position of a character in a string is very difficult without access to the rendering library. You could probably get it right 99+% of the time by not counting combining characters and zero-width characters. (Do you have to consider line breaks, tabs and other typesetting characters, too?)

Comment: @TomBlodget: No I need not worry about the line breaks, tabs and other things.

Comment: There are several classes of characters that are going to mess this up: 
 combining characters, as you've discovered, but also control characters and non-spacing characters.  There's also the issue of bi-directional (BiDi) text and the codepoints that influence the BiDi algorithm.  And if your rendering algorithm substituted ligatures, that do can lead to a discrepancy between the number of codepoints and the number of glyphs.